# Shin pain while running on pavement only?

Tags: running

I can comfortably run about 13-14 miles on a trail without any problems whatsoever. However, yesterday I ran on a paved surface, and after about 1 mile, I started feeling a lot of pain in my shins. I didn't want to exacerbate the problem, so I stopped at 2 miles.

Why am I experiencing such a big difference when running on pavement? About two months ago, I could run 5-6 on pavement without issue, but now it's just pain, pain, pain.

Comment: I was going to answer "shin splints", but at 1/5 of your accustomed distance on roads that seems untypical. And  one "pain" might be OK, but "pain, pain, pain" has me worried: get it checked by a doctor.

Comment: I agree with Fillet. My immediate answer would be shin splints because I have them too when I do pavement running but not trail or grass or anything like that. I'd say have it checked out. Make sure to ice.